# How to get environment variables in Electron after packaging?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have tried 2 ways to get `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.

The first:

```js
process.env['ANDROID_HOME']
```

The second:

```js
const cmd = '.' + __dirname + '/shell/android_home.sh'
const ah = spawn(cmd)
    ah.stderr.on('data', stderr => {
        showAlert('stderr=' + stderr)
        console.log("stderr=" + stderr)
    })
    ah.on('error', error => {
        showAlert('error=' + error)
        console.log("error=" + error)
    })
    ah.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        showAlert('data=' + data)
    })
    ah.on('close', (statusCode) => {
        showAlert('statusCode=' + statusCode)
        console.log('statusCode=' + statusCode)
    })
```

android_home.sh

```
//The shell file is very simple
#!/bin/bash

echo "$ANDROID_HOME"
```

The 2 ways works fine during the developing, but after packaging to a macOS app, I can not get `ANDROID_HOME`.